# read signed number from a char vector

Tags: c, fgets, negative-number

I got this problem and I really need help, I'll be so thankful: 
When I input a negative number using `fgets()` and then try to verify is the string input by the user in the char array read by `fgets()` is a number with `isdigit()` I get always positive numbers, is there any way to read negative numbers. (I only need to read numbers but can use scanf because when It read a character it makes me a mess)

here's a part of the code:

```
char op[30];
int a[30];

int text_ssalto() {
    size_t len = strlen(op);
    fgets(op, sizeof(op), stdin);
    len = strlen(op);
    if (len > 0) {
        op[len - 1] = '\0';
    }

    if (isdigit(*op)) {
        sscanf(op, "%d", &a[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe somewhere else is wrong in your code, here is a sample which is similar to yours and it is working. Did you include the correct headers?

```
#include "ctype.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main ()
{
        char op[30];
        fgets(op, sizeof(op), stdin); /* input -11 */
        printf("%s\n", op); /* output -11 */
        if (isdigit(*op)) {
            printf("wrong\n"); // never got printed if input is negative
            sscanf(op, "%d", &a[x]); // read positive number     
        }
        else {
              sscanf(op + 1, "%d", &a[0]); // now a[0] has the positive part
              a[0] = -a[0]; // make it negative if you want.
        }

        return (0);
}
```

Comment: yes I've included all those headers but can't get it

Comment: I think you can test my code and to see if it works. I don't think `isdigit` not working for `-` as the first char as mentioned by the other answer. At least on my machine, it works.

Comment: yeah it works but when I try to print after the if condition it prints me a positive number

Comment: when I print the a[x] I supposed that the `isdigit()` don't store the `-` cause it's not a number

Comment: If the test for `isdigit(*op)` fails, the code never go inside of the if statement. I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: This works wonderful that's exactly what I want thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isdigit(*op)) {
```

will not work if the first character is `'-'`.

Instead of using

```
if (isdigit(*op)) {
    sscanf(op, "%d", &a[x]);
}
```

use

```
if ( sscanf(op, "%d", &a[x]) == 1 )
{
   // Got a number.
   // Use it.
}
```

The function contains extraneous checks that don't seem to be necessary. It can be simplified to:

```
int text_ssalto() {
   fgets(op, sizeof(op), stdin);
   if ( sscanf(op, "%d", &a[x]) == 1)
   {
      // Got a number
      // Use it.
   }

   return 0;
}
```